# Jquery return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a code:

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function(){
return this.each(function() {
    attributes = "test";

    return attributes;
});}
```

But when I call

```
 var1 = $(this).MyFunction();alert(var1);
```

I got an [object], but not the "test".

How to allow jquery plugin return a some value?

Comment: well, you were simply returning the function being passed to `each` rather than returning your `MyFunction` extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery plugins are generally designed to return a jQuery object so you can chain method calls:

```
jQuery("test").method1().method2() ...
```

If you want to return something else, use the following syntax:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myFunction: function( args ) {
            attributes = "test";

            return attributes;
    }
});
```

, or access it via its index using `[]`.

Comment: Thanks, syntax "jQuery.fn.extend" helps me. 

P.S. You forgot "fn" in answer.

Comment: Good Catch, thanks! I was looking at the isArray example in the jQuery source code, but forgot that isArray is a "static" call that would not need the fn.

Answer (score 6):

Here is once again your code:

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function() { #1
   return this.each(function() {    #2
      return "abc";                 #3
   });                              #4
};                                  #5
```

Now let's check what every line do.

1. We declare property `MyFunction` which is a function for every jQuery object.
2. This line is first and the last statement of `jQuery.MyFunction()`. We **return** the result of `this.each()`, not the result of lambda-function (used as a argument for `jQuery.each()`). And `this.each()` returns itself so the final result is that you get jQuery object returned.

Lines 3-5 are not important in fact.

Just consider those two examples:

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        return "abc";
    });
};

jQuery.fn.AnotherFunction = function() {
    return "Hello World";
};

var MyFunctionResult = $(document).MyFunction();
var AnotherFunctionResult = $(document).AnotherFunction();

alert(MyFunctionResult);
alert(AnotherFunctionResult);
```

Comment: Your second example should be the accepted answer since it is more succinct and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe jQuery returns the object, so you can maintain the chainability of diffrent functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps use

```
var1 = $(this)[0].MyFunction();alert(var1);
```

But I'm not sure if that is what you want or if your code works at all. What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure you want to call `this.each()`?

Like the others said, jQuery returns jQuery objects in most cases, and accessing the actual object can be accomplished using an indexer `[]` or the `get` method.

Comment: Did not know you could use the get method for this - could you please post an example?

Comment: For example you could write `$(".someClass").get(0);`. Or am I mistaken here?