# Javascript - Object loses its value on function exit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this strange problem. In my code, I have a variable named `val1` which gets a value after a jQuery call, but after exiting the jQuery function it loses its value.

Here's the code:

```
var val1;
$.getJSON('some address', null, function (result) {
    val1 = result.names[0].name;
    alert(val1); //first alert
});
alert(val1); // second alert
```

On first alert, I get the needed value, but on the second Alert - I get `undefined`.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438685/jquery-return-value) and a [million others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+return+value).

Comment: @meagar: How is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438685/jquery-return-value ?

Comment: this is not a duplicate. I don't get an object - but I lose the value of the var.

Comment: You aren't losing the value, you just haven't yet set the value by the time the "second alert" fires (which is actually the one that fires first).

Comment: @balpha Ehh, pasted the wrong URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second `alert` is executed before the value is set. Or vice versa: The callback is executed after the second `alert`.

The Ajax call is **asynchronous**.

Comment: uhhh... an interesting one. Can this be overcome somehow?

Comment: @roman: You could make the Ajax request synchronous, but I strongly advice against it. You loose all the benefits of Ajax imo. Just add everything that has to deal with the return value inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to fix the issue :)